# Casting JDom 1.1.3 Element to Document without DocumentBuilderFactory or DocumentBuilder

Tags: java, xml, jdom

I need to find the easier and the efficient way to convert a JDOM element (with all it's tailoring nodes) to a `Document`. `ownerDocument( )` won't work as this is version `JDOM 1`.

Moreover, `org.jdom.IllegalAddException: The Content already has an existing parent "root"` exception occurs when using the following code.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFac = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFac.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = null;
Element elementInfo = getElementFromDB();
doc = new Document(elementInfo);
XMLOutputter xmlOutput = new XMLOutputter();
byte[] byteInfo= xmlOutput.outputString(elementInfo).getBytes("UTF-8");
String stringInfo = new String(byteInfo);
doc = dBuilder.parse(stringInfo);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use the following method of the element.

```
Document doc = <element>.getDocument();
```

Refer the [API documentation](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs.1.1/org/jdom/Document.html#getDocument()) It says

*Return this parent's owning document or null if the branch containing this parent is currently not attached to a document.*

Answer (score 0):

JDOM content can only have one parent at a time, and you have to detatch it from one parent before you can attach it to another. This code:

> ```
> Document doc = null;
> Element elementInfo = getElementFromDB();
> doc = new Document(elementInfo);
> ```

if that code is failing, it is because the `getElementFromDB()` method is returning an Element that is part of some other structure. You need to 'detach' it:

```
Element elementInfo = getElementFromDB();
elementInfo.detach();
Document doc = new Document(elementInfo);
```

OK, that solves the `IllegalAddException`

On the other hand, if you just want to get the document node containing the element, JDOM 1.1.3 allows you to do that with [`getDocument`](http://jdom.org/docs/apidocs.1.1/org/jdom/Content.html#getDocument()):

```
Document doc = elementInfo.getDocument();
```

Note that the doc may be null.

To get the top most element available, try:

```
Element top = elementInfo;
while (top.getParentElement() != null) {
    top = top.getParentElement();
}
```

In your case, your `elementInfo` you get from the DB is a child of an element called 'root', something like:

```
<root>
    <elementInfo> ........ </elementInfo>
</root>
```

That is why you get the message you do, with the word "root" in it:

> ```
> The Content already has an existing parent "root"
> ```